# Change img src using jQuery without refresh?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I change img src using jQuery without refresh? src is pulled from MySQL

Code:

```
<li><a><img src="pic1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="pic2.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="pic3.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="pic4.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="pic5.jpg" /></a></li>
```

Comment: ajax is all you need

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$.ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and `.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "foo.php"
})
.done(function(data) {
  $('img').attr('src', data);
});
```

Comment: It does affect all the img tag?

Comment: Yes, in this is example `$('img')` is selector for all images.

Comment: Ok, I will check. Thanks